# Change to Application Setting is not showing up at runtime

Tags: c#, settings, application-settings

I have an application that's dealing with a required list of files it has to manipulate when run.  I wanted to add a couple of files to this list.  The list of files is stored in a setting.  The scope of the setting is "Application".  I added my two files to the list (via project properties -> settings), and saved everything.  My files now appear there.  My files are showing up in the app.config for this project under ApplicationSettings.

But when I run the application this line of code:

```
StringCollection requiredFiles = mySettings.UpdatePackageRequiredFiles;
```

Does not include my files.

`mySettings` is the right type; it's the project where the settings exist.  Further, there is nowhere in the project UpdatePackageRequiredFiles is being written to and you can't write to an Application scope setting at run-time anyway (or so I understand).

To spice up the mystery a little bit, there are 3 files appearing in the list whose existences are a complete mystery.  They do not appear when viewing the settings in the designer, or in the source file.  So what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a configuration file with an identically named setting that the application was getting the list of files from.